# R: multiply all columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

My dataframe has all numeric columns (such as mtcars). How to create a new column that shows the product of all the columns? My attempt:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 mtcars %>% mutate(product=prod(mpg:carb))
```

yields incorrect product

```
    mpg  cyl  disp  hp  drat    wt   qsec  vs am  gear  carb      product
1  21.0   6 160.0  110  3.90  2.620  16.46  0  1    4    4      8.515157e+18
2  21.0   6 160.0  110  3.90  2.875  17.02  0  1    4    4      8.515157e+18
...
```

Comment: I'd probably do `mtcars %>% mutate(prod = apply(., 1, prod))`, honestly

Comment: not as fast as @akrun's solution with Reduce but works

Comment: Honestly, it's a sort of weird operation for a data.frame. There's a good chance you should reshape to long form or just use matrices instead.

Comment: Will reshaping to long or converting to a matrix make it faster than just using Reduce?

Comment: Doubtful, but none of the options will be slow enough to matter if you're using `*` or `prod` as the function unless the data is truly enormous. What it will do is make everything less convoluted to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce`

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(Prod = Reduce(`*`, .))
```

---

Or use `do`

```
mtcars %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    do(data.frame(., Prod = prod(unlist(.))))
```

Comment: @OttToomet  The OP's question is `R: multiply all columns in a dataframe`